# Colocar função autoplay no slider

Tags: javascript

Oi, tenho um slider que as imagens não são passadas de forma automatica, queria colocar um autoplay no js para as imagens irem passando de forma automática.

Código JS:

```
{
// From https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};

class Slideshow {
    constructor(el) {
        this.DOM = {};
        this.DOM.el = el;
        this.settings = {
            animation: {
                slides: {
                    duration: 600,
                    easing: 'easeOutQuint'
                },
                shape: {
                    duration: 300,
                    easing: {in: 'easeOutQuad', out: 'easeOutQuad'}
                }
            },
            frameFill: 'url(#gradient1)'
        }
        this.init();
    }
    init() {
        this.DOM.slides = Array.from(this.DOM.el.querySelectorAll('.slides > .slide'));
        this.slidesTotal = this.DOM.slides.length;
        this.DOM.nav = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.slidenav');
        this.DOM.nextCtrl = this.DOM.nav.querySelector('.slidenav-item-next');
        this.DOM.prevCtrl = this.DOM.nav.querySelector('.slidenav-item-prev');
        this.current = 0;
        this.createFrame(); 
        this.initEvents();
    }
    createFrame() {
        this.rect = this.DOM.el.getBoundingClientRect();
        this.frameSize = this.rect.width/12;
        this.paths = {
            initial: this.calculatePath('initial'),
            final: this.calculatePath('final')
        };
        this.DOM.svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
        this.DOM.svg.setAttribute('class', 'shape');
        this.DOM.svg.setAttribute('width','100%');
        this.DOM.svg.setAttribute('height','100%');
        this.DOM.svg.setAttribute('viewbox',`0 0 ${this.rect.width} ${this.rect.height}`);
        this.DOM.svg.innerHTML = `
            <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ED4264">
                    <!--animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#ED4264; #FFEDBC; #ED4264" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate-->
                </stop>
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFEDBC">
                    <!--animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#FFEDBC; #ED4264; #FFEDBC" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate-->
                </stop>
            </linearGradient>
            </defs>
            <path fill="${this.settings.frameFill}" d="${this.paths.initial}"/>
        `;
        this.DOM.el.insertBefore(this.DOM.svg, this.DOM.nav);
        this.DOM.shape = this.DOM.svg.querySelector('path');
    }
    updateFrame() {
        this.paths.initial = this.calculatePath('initial');
        this.paths.final = this.calculatePath('final');
        this.DOM.svg.setAttribute('viewbox',`0 0 ${this.rect.width} ${this.rect.height}`);
        this.DOM.shape.setAttribute('d', this.paths.initial);
    }
    calculatePath(path = 'initial') {
        if ( path === 'initial' ) {
            return `M 0,0 0,${this.rect.height} ${this.rect.width},${this.rect.height} ${this.rect.width},0 0,0 Z M 0,0 ${this.rect.width},0 ${this.rect.width},${this.rect.height} 0,${this.rect.height} Z`;
        }
        else {
            return {
                step1: `M 0,0 0,${this.rect.height} ${this.rect.width},${this.rect.height} ${this.rect.width},0 0,0 Z M ${this.frameSize},${this.frameSize} ${this.rect.width},0 ${this.rect.width},${this.rect.height} 0,${this.rect.height} Z`,
                step2: `M 0,0 0,${this.rect.height} ${this.rect.width},${this.rect.height} ${this.rect.width},0 0,0 Z M ${this.frameSize},${this.frameSize} ${this.rect.width-this.frameSize},${this.frameSize} ${this.rect.width},${this.rect.height} 0,${this.rect.height} Z`,
                step3: `M 0,0 0,${this.rect.height} ${this.rect.width},${this.rect.height} ${this.rect.width},0 0,0 Z M ${this.frameSize},${this.frameSize} ${this.rect.width-this.frameSize},${this.frameSize} ${this.rect.width-this.frameSize},${this.rect.height-this.frameSize} 0,${this.rect.height} Z`,
                step4: `M 0,0 0,${this.rect.height} ${this.rect.width},${this.rect.height} ${this.rect.width},0 0,0 Z M ${this.frameSize},${this.frameSize} ${this.rect.width-this.frameSize},${this.frameSize} ${this.rect.width-this.frameSize},${this.rect.height-this.frameSize} ${this.frameSize},${this.rect.height-this.frameSize} Z`
            }
        }
    }
    initEvents() {
        this.DOM.nextCtrl.addEventListener('click', () => this.navigate('next'));
        this.DOM.prevCtrl.addEventListener('click', () => this.navigate('prev'));
        
        window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(() => {
            this.rect = this.DOM.el.getBoundingClientRect();
            this.updateFrame();
        }, 20));
        
        document.addEventListener('keydown', (ev) => {
            const keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
            if ( keyCode === 37 ) {
                this.navigate('prev');
            }
            else if ( keyCode === 39 ) {
                this.navigate('next');
            }
        });
    }
    navigate(dir = 'next') {
        if ( this.isAnimating ) return false;
        this.isAnimating = true;

        const animateShapeInTimeline = anime.timeline({
            duration: this.settings.animation.shape.duration,
            easing: this.settings.animation.shape.easing.in
        });  
        animateShapeInTimeline
            .add({
                targets: this.DOM.shape,
                d: this.paths.final.step1
            })
            .add({
                targets: this.DOM.shape,
                d: this.paths.final.step2,
                offset: `-=${this.settings.animation.shape.duration*.5}`
            })
            .add({
                targets: this.DOM.shape,
                d: this.paths.final.step3,
                offset: `-=${this.settings.animation.shape.duration*.5}`
            })
            .add({
                targets: this.DOM.shape,
                d: this.paths.final.step4,
                offset: `-=${this.settings.animation.shape.duration*.5}`
            });

        const animateSlides = () => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const currentSlide = this.DOM.slides[this.current];
                anime({
                    targets: currentSlide,
                    duration: this.settings.animation.slides.duration,
                    easing: this.settings.animation.slides.easing,
                    translateX: dir === 'next' ? -1*this.rect.width : this.rect.width,
                    complete: () => {
                        currentSlide.classList.remove('slide-current');
                        resolve();
                    }
                });
    
                this.current = dir === 'next' ? 
                    this.current < this.slidesTotal-1 ? this.current + 1 : 0 :
                    this.current > 0 ? this.current - 1 : this.slidesTotal-1; 
                
                const newSlide = this.DOM.slides[this.current];
                newSlide.classList.add('slide-current');
                anime({
                    targets: newSlide,
                    duration: this.settings.animation.slides.duration,
                    easing: this.settings.animation.slides.easing,
                    translateX: [dir === 'next' ? this.rect.width : -1*this.rect.width,0]
                });
    
                const newSlideImg = newSlide.querySelector('.slide-img');
                anime.remove(newSlideImg);
                anime({
                    targets: newSlideImg,
                    duration: this.settings.animation.slides.duration*4,
                    easing: this.settings.animation.slides.easing,
                    translateX: [dir === 'next' ? 200 : -200, 0]
                });
    
                anime({
                    targets: [newSlide.querySelector('.slide-title'), newSlide.querySelector('.slide-description'), newSlide.querySelector('.slide-btn')],
                    duration: this.settings.animation.slides.duration*2,
                    easing: this.settings.animation.slides.easing,
                    delay: (t,i) => i*100+100,
                    translateX: [dir === 'next' ? 300 : -300,0],
                    opacity: [0,1]
                });
            });
        };

        const animateShapeOut = () => {  
            const animateShapeOutTimeline = anime.timeline({
                duration: this.settings.animation.shape.duration,
                easing: this.settings.animation.shape.easing.out
            });  
            animateShapeOutTimeline
                .add({
                    targets: this.DOM.shape,
                    d: this.paths.final.step3
                })
                .add({
                    targets: this.DOM.shape,
                    d: this.paths.final.step2,
                    offset: `-=${this.settings.animation.shape.duration*.5}`
                })
                .add({
                    targets: this.DOM.shape,
                    d: this.paths.final.step1,
                    offset: `-=${this.settings.animation.shape.duration*.5}`
                })
                .add({
                    targets: this.DOM.shape,
                    d: this.paths.initial,
                    offset: `-=${this.settings.animation.shape.duration*.5}`,
                    complete: () => this.isAnimating = false
                });
        }

        animateShapeInTimeline.finished.then(animateSlides).then(animateShapeOut);
    }
};

new Slideshow(document.querySelector('.slideshow'));
imagesLoaded('.slide-img', { background: true }, () => document.body.classList.remove('loading'));
```

};

Link do Slider: http://ugla.us/SLIDER-NAO-OVAL/

Busquei a parte time mais não entendi direito.

Answer (score 0):

sem código de terceiros, a única dependência é da jquery:

Primeiro eu crio a div que vai conter as imagens com a propriedade overflow hidden e determinando width e height. dentro dela coloco uma div com a largura total das imagens a serem exibidas e dentro desta as imagens propriamente ditas.

```
 <div style=overflow:hidden;width:100%>
    <div class=slide style=width:1000px>
       <img class='slide_img ativo' style=width:250px>
       <img class=slide_img style=width:250px>
       <img class=slide_img style=width:250px>
       <img class=slide_img style=width:250px>
    </div>
 </div>
```

as imagens dentro da div devem ter uma classe comum para que eu possa
Uso o setInterval relacionado a função slide para disparar a cada 5 segundos o movimento.
Dentro da função eu crio uma animação para mover a div interna através do margin-left e ela se esconde no fundo da div anterior que tem overflow:hidden.

```
<script>

setInterval(slide,5000);
function slide(){
    elemento = $('.ativo').next();
    if(elemento.hasClass('slide_img')){
        x = parseInt($('.slide').eq(0).css('margin-left')) / 250;

        final = (x - 1) * 250;
        $('.slide').animate({'margin-left': final},500);
        elemento = $('.ativo');
        elemento.next().addClass('ativo');
        elemento.removeClass('ativo');
    }else{
        $('.slide').css('margin-left',0);
        $('.ativo').removeClass('ativo');
        $('.slide_img').eq(0).addClass('ativo');
    }
}
</script>
```

repare que o valor 250 do tamanho do width aparece também 2x na função. Atualize para a largura que deseja para cada imagem

Comment: Oi obrigado pela resposta, tentei executar o snippet não funcionou, posso chamar voçê no chat? ou pode rever o codigo, vai ser otimo pra mim. obg

Comment: de nada, fiz o teste e alterei o que precisava